# PHP inside a Bootstrap Modal Not Working

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-modal

Is there something that prevents PHP from being displayed in a Bootstrap modal?

I cannot get this simple echo to work inside my modal.

```html
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        
       <?php echo "Test"; ?>
       
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you add the same PHP code just outside of the modal, what happens?

Comment: is it in a html file?

Comment: Echo works fine outside of modal and yes I'm using MYSQL for my database.

Answer (score 2):

My apologies... I found out what the issue was. The **CSS** styling on the div was for some reason set to `"display: none;"`. It works now. Thanks!